# There is already an active transaction error on PDO->beginTransaction()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, transactions

I have an app built on CakePHP. Have 4 environments for app - local, testing, acceptance and production.
Suddenly on only one of them (of course it's production) I started getting problems with transactions.
The error I get is:

```
There is already an active transaction
#0 /.../lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(2294): PDO->beginTransaction()
#1 /.../lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1749): DboSource->begin()
#2 /.../app/Model/AppModel.php(499): Model->save(Array, true, Array)
.....
```

MySQL versions and settings seem to be identically on all environments, maybe the only difference it's *max_connections*. Also recently we didn't have CakePHP framework update, and app code is the same on environments.

Debug shows me that there are 2 BEGIN transactions call in a row during script execution, but as official MySQL doc says:

> Transactions cannot be nested. This is a consequence of the implicit
>   commit performed for any current transaction when you issue a START
>   TRANSACTION statement or one of its synonyms.

so I suppose it should not be a problem, plus on all environments there are the same 2 BEGIN, and everything just works fine there.

Something tells me that if everything is ok on 3 of 4 environments, the reason is in environment, but I have no idea what it can be, and google doesn't say to much about.

What can be the reason, where I should look for?

Comment: You begin transactions twice, that's the reason. To solve it - just don't do that.

Comment: But it's done in implicit way by framework, and also previous transaction should be committed automatically according to MySQL doc. Plus again the question is still open - why then the same code works fine on 3 other environments?

Comment: It does not matter - why is it invoked twice in this environment?

Comment: In this specific case system tries to perform DB migration. Whole migration wrapped into transaction, and inside migration there is a data save, which in its turn also begins transaction. But we found one another case with related data saving, and there is simply associated data save, but the same problem. The thing is that this second case also appears only on production.

Comment: So, after a transaction was `begin`, has it been `commit`ted before the next one was started?

Comment: At least not by code, as I can see. So I supposed maybe it's done implicit on MySQL layer.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of help you actually are waiting for. The fact: transaction is started twice. Take debugger and debug why it happens

Comment: Well, I'm 100% sure exactly same works fine on all other environments, with same code, same mysql version etc, so I'm trying to find an answer - why so, and what can be the reason of that (maybe some mysql settings e.g.), and how it can be fixed. The very same code was working also on production for years, and nothing was changed in this specific code for months, how is that possible that suddenly behavior changed (recently we moved to AWS from another hosting btw, but all environments are on AWS also)

Comment: " I'm 100% sure exactly same works fine on all other environments, with same code, same mysql version" --- it does not matter. And as you can see - it's not helpful. "so I'm trying to find an answer" --- take a debugger and find it. Debugger is what gives you answers, not comparing versions.

Comment: Well, there is a flaw in code with db connections substitution, and exception with already started transaction appeared on production only, because only there connection was persistent. So looks like I caught really tough bug, and fixed it! Thanks @zerkms for perseverance!